# Coefficient of Drag (Cd) Question

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow, drag

Question: [image]

what i thought; see below.

[image]

we do not know density if i where to use that formula on the image file .

and i a m wondering why i was given the Reynolds number .

need help.

Comment: R in the question is not the Reynolds number, it is the universal gas constant. Use that to find the density. It can't be the Reynolds number, because it's units are given. Reynolds number is a dimensionless quantity!

Comment: oh i see, so when given R what equation do we use to find density?

Comment: Density = P / (R T) : easy mnemonic is prat ....  That value of R is for air....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the formula you need is Density = P /(R*T) and the value of R you have been given is for air.

Once you have re-worked your answer then you should calculate the Reynolds number and then you can check your result here : 
[Drag on a sphere by NASA](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/dragsphere.html)